# Como puedo hacer que los elementos de un accordion list no se muestren expandidos por defecto

Tags: reactjs, react-native, accordion

Estoy haciendo uso del componente [List.accordion](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/list-accordion.html) de la libreria [react-native paper](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/).
La primera vez que se renderiza el componente se muestran los accordions sin expandir (que es el comportamiento esperado), pero al desplegar una opcion, pasar a otra pantalla y volver, el accordion continua deplegado.

Lo que deseo hacer es que retorne a su valor por defecto (sin expandir) al pasar a otra pantalla

**Componente Accordion**

```
import {List, Divider} from "react-native-paper";
import React, {useState} from "react";

const Accordion = () => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const handlePress = () => setExpanded(!expanded);
  const options = [
    {
      title: "Opcion 1",
      icon: "phone",
      disabled: false
    },
    {
      title: "Opcion 2",
      icon: "file",
      disabled: false
    },
  ];
  
  return (
     <View>
  <List.Accordion
    title="My Accordion"
    style={{height: 60}}
    expanded={expanded}
    onPress={ () => handlePress() }
    left={(props) => (
      <List.Icon {...props} color="#06D7A0" />
    )}
    theme={{colors: {primary: "#06D7A0", text: "gray"}}}
    >
    {options.map((item, i) => (
      <List.Item
        title={item.title}
        key={i}
        titleStyle={{
          color: "white",
          fontFamily: "Lato-Regular",
          fontSize: 17,
        }}
        style={[
          {backgroundColor: item.disabled ? "#D6DADD" : "#06D7A0"},
        ]}
        left={(props) => (
          <List.Icon
            {...props}
            icon={item.icon}
            color="white"
            type="font-awesome"
            size={20}
          />
        )}
        disabled={item.disabled}
        onPress={() => toast(item.page)}
      />
    ))}
  </List.Accordion>
  <Divider />
</View>

   )


}

export default Accordion;
```

**Componente Donde utilizo el Accordion**

import React from 'react';
import Accordion from 'Accordion'

```
const App = () => {
    renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
    <Accordian
        title={item.title}
        icon={item.icon}
        data={item.data}
    />
    )

    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
          <FlatList
                data={miData}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
            />
        </View>
    )

}
```

Como puedo hacer para que al cambiar de pantalla los elemento de la lista no esten expandido.

Comment: De donde vienes ese _collapse_ que está en el `useState`?

Comment: Era una variable de prueba que estaba enviando por props desde el componente padre, pero no funcionó. Lo edite y el valor que estoy utilizando es false.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy notando que creas una función `handlePress` y la estás llamando dentro de otra función ejecutando la directamente al momento que se renderiza y es por eso que cambia el gancho `expanded` a true, trata de probar cambiando el `onPress` en el componente `List.Accordion`, cambia `onPress={()=>{ handlePress() }` por `onPress={handlePress}`, lo asumí como una respuesta ya que no me entraría toda la explicación en un comentario, ojalá sea ese el problema y pueda ayudarte, de no ser así seguiré investigando tu código para poder ayudar

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, el metodo handlePress despliega correctamente los elementos del Accordion list. El problema es cuando paso a otra pantalla y regreso a la que contiene los accordions; siguen expandidos aquellos que expandi previamente

Comment: osea que la primera vez que lo visualizas el acordeón se ve cerrado, pero si lo abres y luego cambias de screen y vuelves a la misma el acordeón sigue abierto pero lo que deseas es que no siga abierto, es así lo que quieres hacer?

Comment: En efecto @Enzo, eso es lo que deseo hacer.